# Why is Rails authentication controller route duplicating auth params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `signup` and `signin` POST routes in a rails controller. `signup` requires an `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation`. `signin` requires an `email` and `password`.

Here is what the routes look like:

```js
class Api::V1::AuthController < ApplicationController

  def signup
    binding.pry <-- inspect the params here
    @user = User.create(user_credential_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @token = encode_token(:user_id => @user.id)
      render json: { :user => @user, :jwt => @token }, :status => :created
    else
      render json: { :error => 'Failed to create user' }, :status => :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  def signin
    @user = User.find_by(:email => user_credential_params[:email])
    # authenticate method comes from bcrypt
    if @user && @user.authenticate(user_credential_params[:password])
      @token = encode_token({ :user_id => @user.id })
      render json: { :user => @user, :jwt => @token }, :status => :accepted
    else
      render json: { :error => 'Invalid credentials' }, :status => :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def user_credential_params
    params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

And `routes.rb`:

```js
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      post '/signup', to: 'auth#signup'
      post '/signin', to: 'auth#signin'
    end
  end
end
```

If I throw a `binding.pry` in either controller action to inspect the params (in this example I am inspecting `signup`), I see the following params (via Postman and using AXIOS in the browser):

`[1] pry(#<Api::V1::AuthController>)> params`

`=> <ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"joelhoelting@aol.com", "password"=>"password123", "password_confirmation"=>"password123", "controller"=>"api/v1/auth", "action"=>"signup", "auth"=>{"email"=>"joelhoelting@aol.com", "password"=>"password123", "password_confirmation"=>"password123"}} permitted: false>`

You can see that the above params are returning duplicates of `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation` within another `[:auth]` param hash. However, I am not supplying a param called `[:auth]` in either postman or browser.

Where is the `[:auth]` param coming from? Is rails automatically adding that param and, if so, why?

In case the context is still unclear here is the Github Repo:
[Link To Repo](https://github.com/joelhoelting/who_said_it_v2_backend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Ruby on Rails automatically [wraps parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) with the current controller name when the JSON sent to the server does not specify any root element.

You can re-configure this behavior in [`config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`](https://github.com/joelhoelting/who_said_it_v2_backend/blob/master/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb).

Answer (score 2):

> Is rails automatically adding that param and, if so, why?

Yes

When I throw a `binding.pry` in `signin` action. Then type `Thread.current.backtrace`

I saw `process_action` method in `action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb` is called. This is [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bc7ed042c4/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb#L243).

According that, Ruby on Rails automatically wraps parameters with the current controller name when [wrap parameters format](https://github.com/joelhoelting/who_said_it_v2_backend/blob/master/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb) include content-type of request. Like @spickermann said.